# Simple way to do math on DataFrame columns via string inputs?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm building a tool that reformats data according to a user's specific needs. I am having the user input the specifications into a `config.json` file.

One of the data types I am working with are .tsv files, for which I am using python's Pandas module to read and manipulate the data as required. I want users to be able to create new columns using mathematical manipulations of old columns. For example:

User wants to take columns A and B to make C using this formula:

`C = (A - B) * 30`

So in the `config.json` they put:

`{"C": "(A - B) * 30"}`

I want that to translate to the python code:

`df["C"] = (df["A"] - df["B"]) * 30`

Is there a Pandas tool that does equation interpretation for column manipulation?

Comment: perhaps eval: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html#pandas.DataFrame.eval

Comment: That looks to be exactly what I was looking for. Thank you @jonathan